# Extra brackets of Position command

Tags: list-manipulation

Command `Position` always comes with two extra curly brackets {{}} when it's just one index for the location. I use [[1,1]] in front of my position commands. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why is using `[[1,1]]` not acceptable? The reason `Position` does this is because in general, there can be more than one position where the element is matched and the position itself might be a list (e.g. in a multi-dimensional array).

Comment: _"Position returns a list of positions in a form suitable for use in Extract, ReplacePart, and MapAt."_

Comment: I think [[1,1]] is the best thing you can do. Moreover, [[1,1]] indicates that it will be an advantage adding 3rd and 4th argument: `Position[expr,val,Automatic,1]` if you didn't already do that...

Comment: an alternative is `First@First@Position` cant say better, just a matter of taste

Answer (score 8):

No, to my knowledge there isn't a better way, but there is a good reason for this behaviour.

First, the element might appear more than once, so `Position` must return a list:

```
Position[{1, 2, 1, 3}, 1]

(* ==> {{1}, {3}} *)
```

Second, you might be searching a more complicated compound expression than a list, e.g. a matrix, so each list element might need to hold more than one index:

```
Position[{{1, 2, 1, 3}, {4, 5, 1, 6}}, 1]

(* ==> {{1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}} *)

Position[{1, {2, 1}}, 1]

(* ==> {{1}, {2, 2}} *)
```

Each index set that `Position` returns can be directly used in the [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Extract.html) function, which is sometimes more convenient to use with `Positions`'s return value than [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html).

You might think that it would be better if `Position` returned a single number as a special case when there's a single match only in a one-dimensional list, such as

```
Position[{1, 2, 3}, 1]

(* ==> {{1}} *)
```

If `Position` did this, programs using it would not be easily generalizable to different inputs and the user would sometimes need to handle this special case.

If you only need the first occurrence of the pattern, you might consider using the fourth argument to your advantage (as Coolwater has pointed out in a comment above):

```
Position[list, patt, Infinity, 1]
```

immediately terminates when the first match is found so it is really useful for large redundant lists. If you are only interested in matches of the topmost level, use the third argument:

```
Position[list, patt, 1, 1]
```

This is equivalent to passing a vector as `list`, that only has depth 1.

Comment: I gladly remove my answer, but would you mind if I edit in the fourth argument for `Position` as a shortcut?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Please do.  We posted seconds apart!